# android save data from background service

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

i have a background service which is working in background and looking for new SMS and creating notification and showing SMS

```
public class SmsBoradcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String SMS = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS)){
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();



        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            }


     // i want to save message some where befor showing notification

            Notification notification = new Notification(context);
            notification.sendNotification(context , "new message" , messages[0].getMessageBody());

        }

    }
}


}
```

everything is working and I'm receiving notification any time even if application is killed and its in background

now the question is that , how can I save those notifications when app is in background?

I tried room database and shared preferences in my service but not worked !!

**Please do not suggest using other methods. I just want to save data in background service , if its possible

Comment: Now the background service is not supported after version "Android O", so you have to use foreground service and in foreground service, you can do anything with your local database.

Comment: Or you can start a workmanager from receiver to store data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Interface :

#### SmsListener

```
public interface SmsListener {
    void onMessageReceived(String message);
}
```

add a Constructor to the `SmsBoradcast` and call it you recieve your add, then you can save your data from wherever you have started this broadcast.

Comment: problem is not receiving message , problem is saving those message to room database or shared preferences which is not possible while application is in background , app is inactive in background and storing data is impossible